# How to append some arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I  try  to append many numpy arrays in one array:

```
path ='C:\\Users\\user\\Traces'
traces= os.listdir(path)
tempTracesHW[HW].append([np.load(os.path.join(path, trace)) for trace in traces])
```

The result of this code is:

```
[[], [[array([[ 0.01437869,  0.01506449,  0.01579909, ...,  0.04166172,
         0.0417285 ,  0.04172079]], dtype=float32),..........., array([[ 0.00418158,  0.00483142,  0.00547356, ..., -0.0032004 ,
        -0.00326461, -0.00333396]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.02872655, -0.02783527, -0.02693371, ...,  0.00331342,
         0.00272522,  0.00211391]], dtype=float32)]], []]
```

But, what I need to have is this structure:

```
[array([ 0.06542969,  0.03808594,  0.07910156, ...,  0.06542969,
        0.07910156,  0.10449219]), array([ 0.0625    ,  0.0390625 ,  0.07421875, ...,  0.14355469,
        0.04296875,  0.06640625])]
```

How to resolve this problem please?

Comment: I don't see any connection between your `result` and your `need`.  `result` is a list of lists of various sizes, some empty, some a nest list with 2d arrays of unknown size.  `need` looks like a list with several 1d arrays. ???

Answer (score 0):

numpy concatenate could be of interest:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

i.e.

```
tempTracesHW[HW] = np.concatenate([tempTracesHW[HW], np.concatenate( [np.load(os.path.join(path, trace)) for trace in traces]))
```

or something.

Comment: It gives this error: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: what does np.concatenate( [np.load(os.path.join(path, trace)) for trace in traces]) give?